# place bullet items in tabular form

Tags: lists, itemize, moderncv

I would like to get the items to show up with the bullet in a tabular form, however, when I try to place the items in a table, I get an error...here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith}


\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City, St. 1111}
\mobile{(000) 000 0000}
\email{uname@email.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle


\section{Coursework}


\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}   {Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item class 1 
\item class 2 
\item class 3 
\item class 4 
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

How can I get the items to show up as:

```
o class 1     o class 2
o class 3     o class 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to choose a bullet, or search through the source code of moderncv to find out what bullet they use for    \item.   \myitem is close, but not exactly the same.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith}


\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City, St. 1111}
\mobile{(000) 000 0000}
\email{uname@email.com}

\newcommand{\myitem}{{\large\color{blue}$\circ$}\hspace{5pt}}%just a bullet

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle


\section{Coursework}


\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}   {Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\newline
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{20pt}}l}
\myitem class 1 & \myitem class 2\\
\myitem class 3 & \myitem class 4
\end{tabular} 
}

\end{document}
```

[image: first]

Alternatively you could do something like this.

```
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item class 1
\item class 3
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item class 2
\item class 4
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: second]

One can also implement a Tikz matrix.  Normal ampersand use appears to be incompatible with moderncv class.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[anchor=west,column sep = 20pt,ampersand replacement = \&]
 {
  \node{\myitem class 1}; \& \node{\myitem class 2}; \\
  \node{\myitem class 3}; \& \node{\myitem class 4}; \\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You will also need:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
```

[image: third]

Comment: John, Could you please add a picture to see the result?

Comment: Full page or cropped?

Comment: Cropped, let's keep things nice and clean :).  Just show what your code does, and what the OP should expect to obtain.  It's kind of a standard procedure when you want to show something you did that "works"

Comment: You could also use a tikz matrix.

Comment: how can the tikz matrix be implemented in this case?

Comment: Matrix is now implemented.  I also played a bit with    \myitem.